# How to create an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

I want to create an iPhone application. But the build should work for iPhone device 3.0 to 4.0.

Please give me some idea for that. Because, I have created an iPhone application. I have installed that application in a device (version 3.1.3), it is working fine. I have tried in iPhone version 4.0 with the same build. But I am getting some error message.

error message:
"entitlements are not valid".

Comment: 1) Let everyone know what the error message is. 2) Install the 4.X SDK and try your application in the simulator. 3) Please reformat your question into something we have a chance at answering :)

Comment: You did "something" wrong in your program so you're getting "some" error when run it on device. Be more specific in your question - tell at least what that error is?

Comment: I am having 2 device. iOS version 3.1.3 and 4.0. If I build an application from xcode 3.2.2, it is working in iOS version 3.1.3. If I build an application from xcode 3.2.3, it is working in iOS version 4.0.

Comment: I noticed when I upgraded from SDK 4.0 to 4.1, I could no longer build for 3.1.3 devices. Maybe something similar is happening to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two settings that you should look at (in your project's info on the build tab):

1) Base SDK - this is the SDK that you are going to link your app with - set this as high as you can.

2) iOS Deployment Target - set this to be iOS 3.0

The first one is the one used by the compiler to make your app.

The second one controls which devices your app can run on (iOS 3.0 means 3.0 and anything above that)

Watch out though - if you use any methods that are only available in iOS 4.0 the app will compile fine but will crash if you run it on a 3.x device - you need to thoroughly test it just to be on the safe side. If you look in the docs each method says which version of iOS it's available on.